# Como acessar item no ArrayList

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Criei um `ArrayList` para um sistema de compra cada objeto é um `Item`(produto), que possui o `nome`, `quantidade` e `preço`. Contudo estou querendo fazer a soma de todos os preços de todos objetos que forem adicionados dentro deste Array para fazer o total da compra.

Alguém sabe como fazer isto?

Classe de teste:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Item> c1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcao=0;

......

case 4:
   System.out.println("--------------");
   System.out.println("TOTAL DA LISTA");
   System.out.println("--------------");
   break;
```

Classe Item

```
public class Item {
public String nome;
public int quantidade;
public double preco;

public Item(){
    ler();
}

public void ler() {
    Scanner lc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite o produto que deseja inserir: ");
    this.nome = lc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade que deseja: ");
    this.quantidade = lc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Digite o valor do produto: ");
    this.preco = lc.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar um `stream` em conjunto com `sum`:

```
double soma = items.stream()
  .mapToDouble(item -> item.getQuantidade() * item.getPreco())
  .sum();
```

Lembre-se de encapsular a quantidade com `private` e criar os `getters` para `quantidade` e `preco`.

---

> [`mapToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-)
>
> Returns a DoubleStream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna um DoubleStream consistindo nos resultados da aplicação da função dada aos elementos deste stream.

---

> [`sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--)
>
> Returns the sum of elements in this stream. Summation is a special case of a reduction.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a soma dos elementos neste stream. A soma é um caso especial de redução.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá:

Primeiro, crie alguns *getters* para seu código:

```
public int getQuantidade(){
return this.quantidade;
}

public double getPreco{
return this.preco;
}
```

Com isso, podemos retornar o preço e a quantidade de determinado item da lista, certo? Bom, aconselho-te a criar um loop, com uma variável para acumular a soma, desta forma:

```
double sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < c1.size() ; i++){
    sum += c1.get(i).getPreco()*c1.get(i).getQuantidade();
}
```

Explicação:
Como `c1` é o nome da sua lista, estamos percorrendo ela com um *for loop*. Temos que o método `c1.get(i)` nos retorna um objeto do tipo Item, que está na posição `i` da lista. Com isso, passamos por todos os elementos da lista, e realizamos a soma.

Answer (score 0):

Sua abordagem está colocando num objeto do modelo de domínio (isto é, um objeto que representa algo do problema que a sua aplicação trata, no caso venda de produtos) um comportamento de ler dados do teclado. Seria como colocar código que salva esses dados no banco ou código que exibe esses dados na tela. Embora tenham relação, não é aí que deveriam estar, pois não são comportamentos do que esse objeto representa.  Num projeto maior isso seria potencialmente problemático para a manutenção.

Além disso, o seu `Item` confunde numa mesma classe os conceitos de `Produto` (devido ao campo `nome`) e `ItemDePedido` (devido aos campos `quantidade` e `preco`).

Sugiro que modele uma classe `Pedido` que possui uma lista de objetos de uma classe `ItemDePedido`, esta com campos `quantidade` e `preco` (além é claro de um campo `produto` que não é o nome mais sim uma referência a um objeto da classe `Produto`, que esta sim pode ter um campo `nome` -- se bem que, vide o final do texto).

Faça essa classe `ItemDePedido` ter um método `getSubtotal()` que retorna a multiplicação desses dois primeiros campos `quantidade` e `preco`.

Esse método `getSubtotal()` é uma operação especializada (responsabilidade) que os objetos `ItemDePedido` são capazes de executar sobre seu estado interno (isto é, seus campos). Isso é mais orientado a objetos.

E por fim na classe `Pedido` crie um método `getTotal()` que percorre a lista invocando cada `itemDePedido.getSubtotal()` e usando para calcular o total do pedido.

Outra responsabilidade apropriada para a classe `Pedido` seria `adicionar(ItemDePedido item)`.

Fica claro assim que um item de pedido deve ser construído (isto é, ter seus campos inicializados) passando os valores para esses campos no construtor já previamente lidos a partir de uma leitura de teclado feita externamente a essa classe.

Por sinal, essa classe `Produto` (que representa uma instância de produto no estoque) não deve ser confundida com `DescricaoDeProduto`, que representa a descrição genérica do produto na loja, que não possui quantidade em estoque e permanece existente mesmo que os produtos saiam de estoque. Talvez então um produto deva ter uma descrição de produto e esta ter um nome.

Para se aprofundar mais, consulte *"Utilizando UML e Padrões"* (3a edição), de Craig Larman.

P.S.: Tudo isso pode ser ignorado e ser feito de maneiras como o pessoal colocou em outras respostas. Se é orientado a objetos e traz os benefícios que essa abordagem propõe, aí é outra história (embora em parte o que foi proposto nelas por ser aplicado aqui). Lembrando que no caso simples pode não parecer tão efetivo, mas OO foi feita para lidar com complexidade. O código pode ficar mais complexo nesse caso mas pelo menos não é baseado numa modelagem arbitrária ou "tirada da cartola".